# Flutter Firebase Storage Upload Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm uploading multiple images to Cloud Storage, I've read I can tap into the stream to display an upload progress bar however I can't see a way to do this.

```
  Future<dynamic> postImage(Asset imageFile) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().toString();
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask _uploadTask =
        reference.putData((await imageFile.getByteData()).buffer.asUint8List());
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await _uploadTask.onComplete;
    return storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [example of how to use the `firebase-storage` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage#-example-tab-) in the FlutterFire repo, that is pretty handy.

That example pretty much performs calls on the `StorageUploadTask task` that you have, to determine the upload state and progress.

```
  String get status {
    String result;
    if (task.isComplete) {
      if (task.isSuccessful) {
        result = 'Complete';
      } else if (task.isCanceled) {
        result = 'Canceled';
      } else {
        result = 'Failed ERROR: ${task.lastSnapshot.error}';
      }
    } else if (task.isInProgress) {
      result = 'Uploading';
    } else if (task.isPaused) {
      result = 'Paused';
    }
    return result;
  }
```

For determining progress, it uses:

```
  String _bytesTransferred(StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return '${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalByteCount}';
  }
```

Which is then used in the `build()` method like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<StorageTaskEvent>(
      stream: task.events,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<StorageTaskEvent> asyncSnapshot) {
        Widget subtitle;
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
          final StorageTaskEvent event = asyncSnapshot.data;
          final StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
          subtitle = Text('$status: ${_bytesTransferred(snapshot)} bytes sent');
        } else {
          subtitle = const Text('Starting...');
        }
```

So this takes the [`events` stream of the `task`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageUploadTask/events.html) and gets the progress information from there.